# wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my user model i've got this code:

```
def job_amount(user)
  parent = Parent.where(parents: {firstname: user.firstname, name: user.name})
  demands = Demand.where(parent_id: parent.pluck(:id))
  demands.sum(:quantity)
end
```

calling this:

```
<%= @user.job_amount.to_s %>
```

raises the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

This means the method expect one argument but you are passing zero

```
<%= @user.job_amount(@user).to_s %>
```

Although, this is very bad

if `job_amount` is an instance method in `User` model you don't need to send `@user` as param you can make use of `self`

**Question:** what is the location of `job_amount(user)` method?

**EDIT**

Changing method to this will also fix the issue

```
def job_amount
  parent = Parent.where(parents: {firstname: firstname, name: name})
  demands = Demand.where(parent_id: parent.pluck(:id))
  demands.sum(:quantity)
end
```

and

```
<%= @user.job_amount.to_s %>
```

Comment: **Great!**.. can you tell me what is the location of `job_amount(user)` method?

Comment: its in my /models/user.rb - why?

Comment: In that case you don't need to pass @user as argument

Answer (score 2):

This is better

```
def job_amount
  parent = Parent.where(parents: {firstname: firstname, name: name})
  demands = Demand.where(parent_id: parent.pluck(:id))
  demands.sum(:quantity)
end
```

Comment: I think this option is better. Also, `.sum(:quantity) `is redundant: just `sum` in enough.

Comment: The other option became like mine finally :P